# Spark Streaming & centralized logging: add executorId to logs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, log4j

I am trying to set up centralized logging for a Spark streaming application. My specific use case is to export driver & executors logs to AWS CloudWatch logs but I think part of my question is agnostic to CloudWatch logs and EMR.

Thanks to [Running Spark on Yarn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) / Debugging your Application, I know how to pass in my own log4j configuration file, and even that `spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir` is available. I am already able to make each executor logs into a local file and to run CloudWatch logs agent on each instance to publish the local file into CloudWatch logs.

The issue with this setup is that logs from all executors are mixed. It is not possible to know which executor produced which event. I had like to add something like the executor id to CloudWatch stream name or directly into to logs. However I don't see how to inject that information from Spark to log4j.

I gave a quick look to `ExecutorRunnable.scala` but failed to spot a suitable environment variable or system property. Are you aware of any property that could fit my need? How do people manage this issue? (even on an ELK stack or whatever)